# How to use Mailchimp template in Magento 2 emails

Tags: magento2, email-templates, magento2.2.3, mailchimp

I am trying to use Mailchimp templates in magento 2 emails instead of magento 2 default email templates.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the generated **HTML code** into the relevant email templates within magento.  Either retrieve from Mail-chimp or send yourself the email and look at the source code.

Email templates are in Magento Admin -> Marketing -> Communications -> Email templates